# Comparing partitions from split() using a nested for loop containing an if statement

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, split

Consider the below MWE that splits a distance matrix and attempts to compare partitions:

```
set.seed(1234) # set random seed for reproducibility

# generate random normal variates
x <- rnorm(5)
y <- rnorm(5)

df <- data.frame(x, y) # merge vectors into dataframe
d <- dist(x) # generate distance matrix

splt <- split(d, 1:5) # split data with 5 values in each partition

# compare partitions

for (i in 1:length(splt)) {
  for (j in 1:length(splt)) {
     if(splt[[i]] != splt[[j]]) {
      a <- length(which(splt[[i]] >= min(splt[[j]]))) / length(splt[[i]])
      b <- length(which(splt[[j]] <= max(splt[[i]]))) / length(splt[[j]])
    }
  }
}
# Error in if (splt[[i]] != splt[[j]]) { : the condition has length > 1
```

The above `for` loop should compare all unique partitions (*i.e.*, (1, 2), (1, 3), ... ,(4, 5)). However, the condition is greater than 1.

The result for comparing partition 1 (`split[[1]]`) and partition 2 (`split[[2]]`) for instance should be `a = b = 1`.

```
a <- length(which(splt[[1]] >= min(splt[[2]]))) / length(splt[[1]])
b <- length(which(splt[[2]] <= max(splt[[1]]))) / length(splt[[2]])
```

I know the solution is to instead use `ifelse()` but there is no `else` within the nested loop.

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your problem the error message? That is, why R does not like your comparison `splt[[i]] == splt[[j]]`? The reason is that we get a vector of comparisons:

```r
> splt[[1]] != splt[[2]]
[1] TRUE TRUE
```

If I understand you correctly, `splt[[i]]` is equal to `splt[[j]]` if all entries are equal and different otherwise. If so, change the comparison to be `!(all(splt[[i]] == splt[[j]]))`.
The total loop looks like this:

```r
for (i in 1:length(splt)) {
    for (j in 1:length(splt)) {
        if (!(all(splt[[i]] == splt[[j]]))) {
            a <- length(which(splt[[i]] >= min(splt[[j]]))) / length(splt[[i]])
            b <- length(which(splt[[j]] <= max(splt[[i]]))) / length(splt[[j]])
        }
    }
}
```