# split() returns "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length"

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, split

### Context

I asked this question recently:

[Comparing partitions from split() using a nested for loop containing an if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74568294)

where I needed to compare partitions generated by `split()` from a distance matrix using the code fix provided by @robertdj

```
set.seed(1234) # set random seed for reproducibility

# generate random normal variates
x <- rnorm(5)
y <- rnorm(5)

df <- data.frame(x, y) # merge vectors into dataframe
d <- dist(x) # generate distance matrix

splt <- split(d, 1:5) # split data with 5 values in each partition


for (i in 1:length(splt)) {
for (j in 1:length(splt)) {
    if (i != j) {
        a <- length(which(splt[[i]] >= min(splt[[j]]))) / length(splt[[i]])
        b <- length(which(splt[[j]] <= max(splt[[i]]))) / length(splt[[j]])
        }
    }
}
```

I generated a MWE where each split contained the same number of elements. I did this just for illustrative purposes, fully knowing that this would not necessarily hold for real data.

As per @Robert Hacken's comment if I instead do

```
d <- na.omit(d[lower.tri(d)])
```

I get partitions of unequal length.

### Real Data

However my real data does not have the "same size" property. My real data contains many more partitions than only 5 in my MWE.

Here is my code

```
splt <- split(dist_matrix, sub("(?:(.*)\\|){2}(\\w+)\\|(\\w+)\\|.*?$", "\\1-\\2", colnames(dist_matrix)))
```

The distance matrix `dist_matrix` contains FASTA headers from which I extract the species names.

I then use `splt` above in the doubly nested loop.

For instance, `splt[[4]]` contains 5 values, whereas `splt[[10]]` contains 9.

```
splt[[4]]
[1] 0.1316667 0.1383333 0.1166667 0.1333333 0.1216667

splt[[10]]
 [1] 0.1450000 0.1483333 0.1316667 0.1316667 0.1333333 0.1333333 0.1166667 0.1166667 0.1200000
```

### Expected Output

For my real problem, each partition corresponds to distances for a single species to all other unique species.  So, if Species X has two DNA sequences representing it and there are 10 species in total, the partition for Species X should contain 20 distances. However I don't want the partition to include the distance between the two sequences for species A.

`splt` would thus contain 10 partitions (each not necessarily of the same length) for all species

The expected output of `a` and `b` is a number between 0-1 inclusive. I think these numbers should be small in my real example, but they are large when I try to run my code, which I think is a consequence of the `warning()`.

### What I've Done

I've read on SO that `%in%` is typically used to resolve the warning

```
In splt[[i]] == splt[[j]] :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

except in my case, I believe I would need `%notin% <- Negate(%in%)`.

However, `%notin%` gives the error in my original post

```
the condition has length > 1
```

### Question

How can my nested loop be altered to remove the warning?

Comment: I'm confused by what you're eventually attempting to achieve. You create/overwrite the values of `a` and `b` when the `if` condition is true ... _every time_ it is true ... and you do nothing with it. This means a couple of things: (1) if the conditional is never true, then `a` and `b` are never defined, which is likely an error; (2) if it is true more than once, you don't know this, and you only know that the values of those variables were valid at some point during your comparisons.

Comment: It seems like the conditional statement `!(all(splt[[i]] == splt[[j]]))` is simply checking to ensure that `splt[[i]]` and `splt[[j]]` are not the same element of `splt`. You could replace this with `i != j`.

Comment: Regardless, it seems as if your assumption that your vector of values will always split into equal-length vectors is not safe. Logically, when comparing `splt[[4]]` and `splt[[10]]`, what is your expected output? Perhaps we need an outer comparison to be more resilient to different-length vectors. Please provide "expected output" given the process you hope to achieve and the previously-defined sample data. (Also, questions should generally be self-sufficient, please copy the generation of sample data from your previous question to this one.) Thanks!

Comment: @r2evans Thanks. On it! Stay tuned.

Comment: @r2evans I've added more details and am happy to clarify further if needed.

Comment: @compbiostats Are you sure what you are getting from `split` is what you want in the first place? Your comment speaks about 5 values in each partition in `splt` but there are only 2 values in each of the 5 elements of `splt`. This is because `d` is not a matrix but a `dist` object (the lower triangle of the distance matrix) and so it is treated as a vector of length 10 by `split`.

Comment: @RobertHacken Good point! If I do `d <- na.omit(d[lower.tri(d)])` I now get partitions of differing lengths, which is closer in structure to my real data

Comment: This has nothing to do with the function `split`

Comment: @compbiostats Please, share at least part of your real data with us and the exact code you use with it. I am afraid you might be actually doing something else than you want to.

Comment: *Again*: Please provide "expected output" given the process you hope to achieve and the previously-defined sample data. By this, I mean some _explicit object_, such as `c(0, 0.2, 0.5, 0.23412, 1)` or a matrix or something else. Base this on the data we have, the random data. This likely means you need to manually calculate what each of those values should be; even if you calculate half of them and provide it in the correct structure (and clearly identify which values are real, which are placeholders), it's a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb by *interpreting* parts of what you say, discarding your code, and seeing what I can come up with. If nothing else, it may spark conversation to explain what about my interpretations are correct (and which are incorrect).

Starting with the `splt` as generated by the random data, then replacing elements 4 and 5 with longer vectors,

```r
set.seed(1234)
x <- rnorm(5)
y <- rnorm(5)
df <- data.frame(x, y)
d <- dist(x)
splt <- split(d, 1:5)
splt[[4]] <- rnorm(4)
splt[[5]] <- rnorm(10)
```

We have:

```r
splt <- list("1" = c(1.48449499149608, 2.62312694474001), "2" = c(2.29150692606848, 0.15169544670039), "3" = c(1.13863195324393, 3.43013887931241), "4" = c(-0.477192699753547, -0.998386444859704, -0.77625389463799, 0.0644588172762693), "5" = c(-0.693720246937475, -1.44820491038647, 0.574755720900728, -1.02365572296388, -0.0151383003641817, -0.935948601168394, 1.10229754620026, -0.475593078869057, -0.709440037512506, -0.501258060594761))
splt
# $`1`
# [1] 1.484495 2.623127
# $`2`
# [1] 2.2915069 0.1516954
# $`3`
# [1] 1.138632 3.430139
# $`4`
# [1] -0.47719270 -0.99838644 -0.77625389  0.06445882
# $`5`
#  [1] -0.6937202 -1.4482049  0.5747557 -1.0236557 -0.0151383 -0.9359486  1.1022975 -0.4755931 -0.7094400 -0.5012581
```

You reference expressions like `which(splt[[i]] >= min(splt[[j]]))`, which I'm interpreting to mean *"what is the ratio of `splt[[i]]` that is above the max value in `splt[[j]]`. Since we're comparing (for example) `splt[[1]]` with all of `splt[[2]]` through `splt[[5]]` here, and likewise for the others, we're going to have a square `matrix` where the diagonal is `splt[[i]]`-vs-`splt[[i]]` (likely not interesting).

Some quick math so we know what we should end up with:

```r
splt[[1]]
# [1] 1.484495 2.623127
range(splt[[2]])
# [1] 0.1516954 2.2915069
```

Since 1 from `[[1]]` is greater than 2's max of 2.29, we expect `0.5` in a comparison between the two (for `>= max(.)`); similarly, none of `[[1]]` is below 0.15, so we expect a `0` there.

Similarly, `[[5]]` over `[[4]]`:

```r
splt[[5]]
#  [1] -0.6937202 -1.4482049  0.5747557 -1.0236557 -0.0151383 -0.9359486  1.1022975 -0.4755931 -0.7094400 -0.5012581
range(splt[[4]])
# [1] -0.99838644  0.06445882

### 2 of 10 are greater than the max
sum(splt[[5]] >= max(splt[[4]])) / length(splt[[5]])
# [1] 0.2

### 9 of 10 are lesser than the min
sum(splt[[5]] <= min(splt[[4]])) / length(splt[[5]])
# [1] 0.2
```

We can use `outer`, but sometimes that can be confusing, especially since in this case we'd need to `Vectorize` the anon-func passed to it. I'll adapt your double-`for` loop premise into nested `sapply` calls.

### Greater than the other's max

```r
sapply(splt, function(y) sapply(setNames(splt, paste0("max", seq_along(splt))), function(z) sum(y >= max(z)) / length(y)))
#        1   2   3    4   5
# max1 0.5 0.0 0.5 0.00 0.0
# max2 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.00 0.0
# max3 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.00 0.0
# max4 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.25 0.2
# max5 1.0 0.5 1.0 0.00 0.1
```

Interpretation and subset validation:

- `1` with `max of 2`: comparing `[[1]]` (first column) with the max value from `[[2]]` (second row), half of `1`'s values are greater, so we have 0.5 (as expected).
- `5` with `max of 4`: comparing `[[5]]` (fifth column) with the max value from `[[4]]` (fourth row), `0.2` meet the condition.

### Less than the other's min

```r
sapply(splt, function(y) sapply(setNames(splt, paste0("min", seq_along(splt))), function(z) sum(y <= min(z)) / length(y)))
#        1   2   3    4   5
# min1 0.5 0.5 0.5 1.00 1.0
# min2 0.0 0.5 0.0 1.00 0.8
# min3 0.0 0.5 0.5 1.00 1.0
# min4 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.25 0.2
# min5 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.00 0.1
```

Same two pairs:

- `1` with `min of 2` (row 2, column 1) is `0`, as expected
- `5` with `min of 4` (row 4, column 5) is `0.2`, as expected

*Edit*: @compbiostats pointed out that while `sum(..)` should produce the same results as `length(which(..))`, the latter may be more robust to missing-data (e.g., `NA` values, c.f., [Difference between sum(), length(which()), and nrow() in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25065501/difference-between-sum-lengthwhich-and-nrow-in-r)). For `sum(..)` to share that resilience, we should add `na.rm=TRUE)` to both `sum(.)` and `min(.)` in the above calls. Thanks @compbiostats!

Comment: Thanks! Just seeing this now, so I will take some time to digest it. Hopefully it generates some conversation.

Comment: To be candid, the next bit of the conversation needs to come from you now. What in my assumptions is incorrect? Are you able to provide concrete expected output?

Comment: This looks fine to me. I'll apply it to my own data and integrate into the pipeline I am currently working on with a colleague. Basically, these results will be outputted to a text file for downstream analysis. Once I do this, then I think I'll have a better idea regarding the desired output.

Comment: One small correction in your code: the anonymous functions should be `function(z) sum(y >= min(z)) / length(y)` and `function(z) sum(y <= max(z)) / length(y)`You just had the min and max switched.

Comment: Yeah, missed that ... I think I projected an assumption from another topic I was working at the same time, thanks for seeing that and reporting back. Glad it helped get to a resolution!

Comment: Thanks again. Is there any reason why you used `sum(...)` as opposed to `length(which(...))` in the `sapply` call? I don't see the equivalence.

Comment: They are functionally the same, I don't know when one will work when the other does not. Having said that, `length(which(..))` is two calls, `sum(..)` is just one call (with the same input); with "small" data (length < 1000), the latter is 3x faster; with larger data, the difference is less extreme but `sum` is still clearly faster.

Comment: To add to my last comment, I found this SO post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25065501/difference-between-sum-lengthwhich-and-nrow-in-r, which answers my question.